# Draw 3-dimensional angles

Tags: 3d, tikz-3dplot, angle

I'm using the following code to generate a sketch of a conic pendulum.

```
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}

\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3.14]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A) at ({cos(deg(-45))},{sin(deg(-45))},0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0,2);

% Body and top
\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
    \draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[fill=gray] (B) circle (0.5pt);
    \draw[->] (B)+(-240:0.25) arc (-240:80:0.25);
\end{pgfonlayer}

% circular path
\draw[dashed] plot[variable=\t, samples=100] ( {cos(deg(\t))}, {sin(deg(\t))}, 0);

% rope
\tikzstyle{rope}=[brown!20!black,double=brown!70!black,double distance=0.5,line width=0.3] %very thick
\draw[rope] (A)--(B) node[midway, right]{$\ell$};

% sketches
\draw (A)--(O) node[midway, xshift=-5, yshift=-3]{$r$};
\draw (O)--(B) node[midway,left]{$h$};
\pic[scale=3][draw, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.15] {angle = O--B--A};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Despite using 3d-plot, the theta angle is a screen-flat 2d-angle. How do I orient it as a 3d angle? Also, How would I add a sketch of the 90 degree angle AOB? I found only [this example](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/the-3dplot-package/) but I find it more confusing than useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it drawing the arc directly. First you need to obtain it buy it's easy if you know `r` and `l`. And last, to draw it all you have to do is change the canvas.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3.14]
% dimensions and coordinates
\def\a{-58} % angle for A point
\def\r{1} 
\def\h{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\t{atan(\r/\h)} % theta angle
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A) at ({\r*cos(\a)},{\r*sin(\a)},0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0,\h);
% Body and top
\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
    \draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[fill=gray] (B) circle (0.5pt);
    \draw[->] (B)+(-240:0.25) arc (-240:80:0.25);
\end{pgfonlayer}
% circular path
\draw[dashed] (0,0,0) circle (1);
% angle
\def\ar{0.5} % angle radius
%\draw[rotate around z=\a,canvas is xz plane at y=0,red] (B) circle (\ar); % <-- uncomment this if you want
\draw[rotate around z=\a,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
    (B) + (0,-\ar) arc (-90:-90+\t:\ar) node [midway,below] {$\theta$};
% rope
\tikzstyle{rope}=[brown!20!black,double=brown!70!black,double distance=0.5,line width=0.3] %very thick
\draw[rope] (A)--(B) node[midway, right]{$\ell$};
% sketches
\draw (A)--(O) node[midway, xshift=-5, yshift=-3]{$r$};
\draw (O)--(B) node[midway,left]{$h$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I made a couple of changes to your code:

1. I added a couple of parameters. This way is easy to make changes.
2. There is no need to convert to `deg` because the trigonometric functions (in pgf) take their arguments in degrees.
3. The base circle can be drawn directly as a circle.
4. There is no need for layers, if you draw last what you have in the foreground layer (I left them anyway).

Comment: Is there also a clean way to rotate not only around an axis through the origin? something like rotate around = {angle, point}?

Comment: @35T41, if I understand what you want, you can define a `scope`, shift the origin to the desired point and then rotate inside the scope whatever you need.